# Does this limit give us the Cantor set?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $K = [0,1], g_{1}x = \displaystyle\frac{x}{3}, g_{2}x = \displaystyle\frac{1}{3}(x+2)$.

Also, $x_{0} = [0,1], x_{1} = g_{1}(x_{0}) \cup g_{2}(x_{0}) = [0, \displaystyle\frac{1}{3}] \cup [\displaystyle\frac{2}{3}, 1],$ etc.

What happens when $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_{n}$?

Don't we just get the Cantor set? What does the proof look like?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say $\lim_{n\to a}x^{n}$, what exactly do you mean there? Under which metric are you limiting this sequence of sets? And what is $a$ in the limit?

Comment: What is $a$ here, did you mean $\infty$? When you say $x^n$, don't you instead mean $x_n$? When you say $g(x_0)$, don't you actually mean $g_1(x_0)\cup g_2(x_0)$? If the answer to all these questions is positive, the answer to your question is yes. The limit of this process is the Cantor set, and it is a limit (in the usual $\epsilon$-$\delta$ sense) in the space of nonempty compact subsets of the plane, with the Hausdorff metric. If you are not familiar with this space, you can interpret the limit simply as the intersection of the $x_n$, noting that $x_0\supset x_1\supset x_2\supset\dots$

Comment: Your right Andres. Sorry for the confusion and being vague. In general do I just consider the nth term of the cantor set then and take the limit as n goes to infinity?